# How to read in quiz questions from database in vb?

Tags: database, vb.net

I'm working on a maths quiz for a school project in Visual Studio 2010 (not by choice). I plan on using an access database to hold each question and the corresponding multiple choice answers, including which is the correct. Something like this: [image: The access database]

The screen design includes the question number, the question, and 4 multiple choice answers. When the user presses an answer, I want the program to score whether they were correct (I'm able to code this) and then increment to the next row in the database and load the next question and set of answers.

I'm unsure how I'd go about loading the database into the program. After each question is completed, I'd increment the table ID so it points to the next question (as shown in the image). After this, the question inside the question field should be loaded into the label I have created.

Sorry if I sound really stupid - I'm just a beginner.

Comment: You're on the right track. First set the question ID to 1. Then load the question from the database for question ID = 1. Display the question and the choices on the form. Store the actual answer in a variable to you can tell if the user pick the right answer. After the user pick a choice, check the stored answer with his answer. If they are equal, increase his score. Then increment the question ID. Repeat until all questions are processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to load the data from the database into your program is using ADO.NET.

You first create a connection object (in the case of an Access database an OleDbConnection) with a connection string pointing to your database. 
How to form the connection string can be found [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/).

Then you use a DataAdapter to load the data from the database into a DataSet where you can access it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks so much - making some progress now! :)